# Logic for Implementing Filters for Search - IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoa-touch, logic

So there is a list of book in an array that I am displaying on my view. I have 3 filters on the top of the view which are like:

(All | Reading level 1 | Reading Level 2 | Reading Level 3) (All | Informational | Literature) (All | Published in 2000-2005 | Published in 2005-2010)

How do I make the filters mutual so that if user has selected reading level 1 and Informational and 2000-2005, then the user will only view the books that are reading level 1 and informational and are published in 2000-2005.

I am doing this in **iOS** for the information and I can't seen to be able to come up with a logic for clean code to combine these 3 filters for the result array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You could get more info [here](http://appworks.radeeccles.com/programming/convert-sql-nspredicate-core-data/)